# Is the quantity for Stripe's subscriptions prorated?

Tags: stripe-payments

For example, let's say over the course of the month the quantity fluctuates like so:

5 6 7 8 7 8 9 10 11 10 11 12 13

Would that be properly prorated given how long each of those quanities "lasts"?

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr... Yes.

From a Stripe [blog post](https://stripe.com/blog/new-recurring-billing-features) announcing the subscription quantity feature: "Prorating kicks in as usual when you change the quantity of a subscription unless you pass prorate as false."

And according to the Stripe API documentation for [updating a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#update_subscription), the `prorate` flag defaults to `true`.